# USE GROUP BY QUERY IN CODEIGNITER

Tags: codeigniter

Can I use group by query in my codeigniter model?
Some articles says it has been removed.
And I cannot get my result array of group by query.

here is my model

```
function get_data2(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_anggaran_rka');
        $this->db->group_by("kode_warna");
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Check this link for official docs. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data

Comment: @Jeevan it,s work thank you